# android alarm manager notify late

Tags: android

I implement an alarm in android but it notifies late most of the time.

In my app I can create more than one alarm at a time, but if do that only last alarm will notify.

Please help me find a solution for this .

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);

    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent1,0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(),3600000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: that is expected behavior. checkout `Note` section in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: this happens when ur phone in sleep mode, right? Then  u may use  WakeLock to keep ur app running when the phone in sleep mode.

Comment: i'm really new to android development. can you any give me sample code for this.

Comment: @yummy even phone in live this happen

Comment: @ayeshdon:as a tricky workaround, set `targetSdkVersion` as 18 in your manifest file and see if it is working.

Comment: @ayeshdon : What do you mean by "late"? A few seconds? A few minutes? An hour? More?

Comment: @Squonk is basically 10s. and also i put two alarm in same time with 1 min different but ist not working. always one alarm not triggered

Comment: Are you using a different requestCode for the different alarms?

Comment: @DanielNugent no .. how do i put id for alarm?

Comment: Look at the answer from @Squonk, use a different `requestCode` in order to set multiple alarms.

Comment: @ayeshdon : 10 seconds seems to be a little inaccurate but as alarms are often only used to be triggered once an hour or once a day or week, 10s isn't too bad.

Answer (score 2):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554883/android-alarm-manager-notify-late#comment47260558_29554883), Android [no longer triggers the alarm at the exact time, unless you explicitly request it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

> **Note**: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see `setWindow`(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and `setExact`(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

This is not possible with repeating alarms, which are always triggered when the system deems it best:

> As of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact.

The question about multiple alarms [seems solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29555425/1587329).

Answer (score 1):

This should set two alarms and also allow the alarms to wake your device if it's asleep...

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

PendingIntent pendingIntent1, pendingIntent2;
Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 1, myIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), 3600000, pendingIntent1);
calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 56);
alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), 3600000, pendingIntent2);
```

Notice the second parameter of `getBroadcast(...)`. This is the `requestCode` and must be unique if you want to set two different alarms at the same time.

Also notice the use of `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` to wake up the device when the alarm is triggered.

Comment: what about in pending intent set as like this pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0  , myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);  i want pass few value with pending intent

Answer (score 0):

//update manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

 <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

// create class AlarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
    Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```

// in main activity

// i am set 1 number alarm, you can call any number of alarm

```
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
AlarmManager alarmManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    callAlarmWithNumber(alarmManager,1);
}

public void callAlarmWithNumber(AlarmManager alarm,int number) {
    switch (number)
    {
        case 1 :
            alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            /* Set the alarm to start at 10:30 AM */
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 42);

            /* Repeating on every 1 minutes interval */
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    1000 * 60 * 1, pendingIntent);
            break;

        default :
            break;
    }

}
```